# Saving individual clicked combox items

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am trying to figure out the thought process behind the following.  From a list of records displayed on the screen (php/mysql, each item will have a combo box or command button to "save to favorites".  I would prefer the combobox, but beggers can't be choosers.  This saved to favorites is a tab that list those items from the combo box or command button.

Make a table and copy the item number into that table and under the "saved to favorites" display those records?  I guess another combobox on each listing to clear it from my favorites???

Did I just answer my own question?  Could it be that easy???

Answer (score 0):

Possibly,

If I understand you right, you could populate an item and it's item value.

Then submit this item number and user_value from a session maybe into a row in a new table, possibly favourites?

Would that work for you?

Unique key in your DB

`unique index(user, item);`

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but how do I avoid duplicates?  user name+item number into 1 field?  I have always worked with command buttons, is it possible the second you click the combobox that it adds that record?  I know there has to be security checks and all.

Comment: what DB system is it? PHPMyAdmin?